# How following URL's will get open-redirection?

Tags: web-application, http, dns, url

Reading about open-redirection from web application hackers handbook came across a test case in which the server-side is validating user supplied data that the application uses to set target for redirection by following rules

1. URL provided by user starts with the applications domain name.

OR

2. URL provided contains the applications domain name.

And to bypass the validation author says an attacker can supply following url but does not mention how the url are working.

1. http://mdsec.net.mdattacker.net
2. http://mdattacker.net/?http://mdsec.net
3. http://mdattacker.net/%23http://mdsec.net

mdsec.net --> legit website that sets target for redirection from user supplied data.

mdattacker.net --> attackers website.

My doubt here is how the mentioned url's will get to the attackers website For e.g Suppose the redirection functionality is as https://shop.com/product/check?checkout=user-supplied-data-here

Here the checkout url redirects user and our application is using above mentioned validation check and attacker supplies one of strings mentioned above OK the validation checks are bypassed But the application will send response to the browser as

HTTP/1.1 301 moved permanently

Location : http://mdattacker.net/?http://mdsec.net

and without any user interaction browser sends request to URL in Location header But we have to redirect a user to mdattacker.net and the browser is requesting http://mdattacker.net/?http://mdsec.net as a result user is not redirected to attackers website.

My doubt here is how the mentioned url's are doing their work of redirecting user to attackers website as mentioned in book is there DNS name resolution involved ?

Comment: A simple **URL Shortener**?